# rails tasks for migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, task

I have this migration but I want to do this with using rails tasks.How can I do that ?

```
User.all.each do |user|
  user.deliver = :twice if user.deliver == :none
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
namespace :my_cool_app do
  task :do_this => :environment do
    User.all.each do |user|
      user.deliver = :twice if user.deliver == :none
    end 
  end
end
```

To run this task type `rake my_cool_app:do_this`. More about rake task is posted [here](http://www.ultrasaurus.com/sarahblog/2009/12/creating-a-custom-rake-task/), bit outdated, but worth a read